# Finding points within overlapping spheres

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have the coordinates for the centers and the radii of multiple spherical surfaces (hollow). These spheres may be of different radii, and some will overlap. Whenever they overlap, I want to eliminate the points along the surface of any sphere that is within another sphere or overlapped, so that I only get the "outside" view, so to speak.

How would I go about finding/eliminating these points of overlap? Is there an existing algorithm for finding these points?

Thanks in advance, and let me know if I can clarify the question better!

**Edit 1:**

The input will be a LAMMPS output file. The important section is below. The first column is the atom id, in order for atoms to be distinguishable. The next 3 are x,y,z coordinates. Radius is given by user input.

```
ATOMS_id     x       y       z  
________    ____    ____    ____

 1             0       0       0
 2          1.76    1.76       0
 3          1.76       0    1.76
 4             0    1.76    1.76
 5          3.52       0       0
 6          3.52    1.76    1.76
 7             0    3.52       0
 8          1.76    3.52    1.76
 9          3.52    3.52       0
10             0       0    3.52
11          1.76    1.76    3.52
12          3.52       0    3.52
13             0    3.52    3.52
14          3.52    3.52    3.52
```

Using the above points and a radius of 1.6, this is the output of my current code (that only generates images).

[image: Sample Output]

The main problem is that my code (which uses the `sphere(n)` and `surf()` functions) draws all parts of the sphere, regardless of whether the points overlap. I want to essentially only get the coordinates that make up the outer surface of the above image, without the interior parts.

[image: Simple Example]

The easier case would be for just two spheres, as above.

Comment: Is there any code that you can show us that illustrates your point?  Also, an image would definitely help in further exemplifying your points.

Comment: How have you discretized the space? Can you give us a simple example of a test case (input and ouput)?

Comment: I added clarification and a sample image in the original post!

Comment: What sort of output to do actually want? You've shown pictures; do you want to render the images more efficiently? Do you want the spheres converted into quadrilateral patches?

Comment: The end goal is to convert the points into an STL file for 3d printing (hence, why I want to remove the interior portions). STL files use triangular patches.

Comment: Are you wedded to matlab? Your input appears to be XYZ positions and maybe radii; turn those into an OpenSCAD file, run it through that and get STL out. Bam, problem foisted off on someone else's code.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to come up with some proof-of-concept algorithm for the 2-sphere case based on these two sources: [src1](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/138583), [src2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101396-is-there-a-function-in-matlab-for-detecting-points-inside-a-polyhedron).

```
%% // Init
clear variables; close all force; clc;
%% // Generate spheres
[X,Y,Z] = sphere(40);
P{1} = unique([X(:),Y(:),Z(:)],'rows');
P{2} = bsxfun(@plus,P{1},[0.75,0,0]);
%% // Generate triangulations
DT{1} = delaunayTriangulation(P{1});
DT{2} = delaunayTriangulation(P{2});
%% // Find points within the other triangulation
isIn1 = ~isnan(tsearchn(P{1}, DT{1}.ConnectivityList, P{2})); 
isIn2 = ~isnan(tsearchn(P{2}, DT{2}.ConnectivityList, P{1})); 
%% // Plotting
newP = [P{1}(~isIn2,:);P{2}(~isIn1,:)];
%// Before:
figure();
surf(X,Y,Z); hold on; surf(X+0.75,Y,Z);
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z');
ylim([0,1]);
%// After:
figure();
scatter3(newP(:,1),newP(:,2),newP(:,3));
ylim([0,1]);
```

These are the results:

- Before:

[image]

- After:

[image]

There are still a few errant points inside the joint volume, but I would argue that the situation is much better than at the beginning.

Note: [This FEX submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37856-inpolyhedron-are-points-inside-a-triangulated-volume-) may be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just find points with distance inferior to radius relatively to eah sphere center and after mesh triangularisation eliminate triangle with points inside another sphere.